# How much water does a Common Boobialla cutting need?

Tags: shrubs, propagation, cuttings

I have a cutting I made about a year ago which took root (not sure when, I only realized when the roots were about 2 inches long). I had the cutting sit in a basic water bottle the whole period of its duration (I didn't change the water). The plant species is a [Myoporum insulare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myoporum_insulare) or a Common Boobialla. I took it out of the bottle 1 week ago. I found a nice bucket, drilled a few holes in the bottom and stuck it in there.

These are the photos I took 2 days ago.

I keep it on an old outdoor chair, which is now just framework. Is it too cold? It gets the direct morning sun then midday it stays under a clear roof which lets a small amount of sunlight through.

[image]

The leaves are feeling more dry than an average Boobialla to my understanding. I was thinking this is due to the sudden climate change (water to soil transition).

Also after I took this photo I realised the white stain. Unsure about what that is, maybe just some bird droppings and it slid off.

[image]

I really do want this to survive, if you could help in any way would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can't do an answer because this question is on hold, but regarding watering, you water only when the surface of the potting medium feels just about dry to  the touch,and when you water, water well. Its not clear whether this cutting was indoors until you potted it up and placed outdoors - if  you didn't harden it off first, then some transition shock is to be expected, which may explain why the leaves seem 'drier than they should' to you.

Comment: Thanks @Bamboo, i wish this came off hold. i did fix the question. but it was my bad for posting such a bad one to begin with haha

Comment: Hi @deviousPriest. Sorry, I didn't notice that you'd updated the question with the information we needed. I've reopened it and pinged Bamboo in chat. Hope you get your answer soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The white deposit does look to be something that's dropped onto the plant rather than it being a disease issue, particularly if, as you say, it came off relatively easily. Otherwise,the plant looks pretty healthy, with plenty of new growth appearing.

This plant is endemic to Australia, particularly coastal areas; although its frost sensitive in that it may yellow and die back a bit if caught in frost, it recovers pretty well after cutting back. As previously commented, water when the surface of the potting medium feels dry to the touch, and water well, allowing the excess to drain away freely.

It's probably sensible to get it in the ground fairly soon, where it'll grow away much better than contained in a pot - it looks big enough to cope if you put it in now, provided you keep it watered till it's established itself properly. More info about this plant generally here https://www.anbg.gov.au/gnp/interns-2010/myoporum-insulare.html

Comment: Thanks @Bamboo, the white stain has faded since then fyi. I also have a rose bush which just started to root from last year(roots getting to about 1.5 cm).